# Polynomial rings and degrees

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an example, if possible, of two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in the indicated rings such that the degree of $f(x)· g(x)$ is not equal to the sum of the degrees of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. If not possible, explain why not.

a) $Z_8[x]$

b) $Z_7[x]$

I am very confused as to how to begin this problem. My book and instructor did not define polynomial rings very well or give any examples. A google search did not yield very much either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a) try $2x\cdot(4x+1)$; b) not possible, because the ring with seven elements is a field.

Comment: Wouldn't the order you mentioned for a) be 2 since for the product and then 2 for the sum? Also why is it that a ring with seven elements is a field. Is it because 7 is a prime?

Comment: Yes $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is a field for any prime  $p$.

Comment: Even better: it is a field if and only if $p$ is prime. This follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. If $a,b\in R$, $a\ne0$, $b\ne0$ and $ab=0$, then the degree of the product
$$
(ax+1)(bx+1)=abx^2+(a+b)x+1=(a+b)x+1
$$
is at most $1$.

An element $a\ne0$ such that there exists $b\ne0$ with $ab=0$ is called a *zero divisor*.

Can you find zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$?

Conversely, suppose $R$ is a domain, that is, if $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

If $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_mx^m$ and $b_0+b_1x+\dots+b_nx^n$ are polynomials with degree $m$ and $n$ respectively (that is, $a_m\ne0$ and $b_n\ne0$), then their product is
$$
f(x)+a_mb_nx^{m+n}
$$
where $f(x)$ has only terms of lower degree than $m+n$. Since $a_mb_n\ne0$, the product has degree $m+n$.

Can you find zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to look for zero divisors, which are non-zero elements $a,b \in R$ such that $ab = 0$.  The main result you can use here is that the degree of $f \cdot g$ is equal to the sum of their degrees if the ring is a domain (i.e. does not contain zero divisors).

Since $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field, it does not contain zero divisors and hence finding the required polynomials is impossible.  You should be able to do the first question by noticing that $\bar{2} \cdot \bar{4} = \bar{0}$.